# Int32.TryParse C# - How to keep the last integer value

Tags: c#, mvvm, tryparse

I'm trying to convert a string to int with

```
Int32.TryParse(input, out int number);
```

and I want to keep the last integer value.
E.g.
If string input = "123" then int number = 123 and if string input = "" or null then int number should stay 123 till input had a new string value.

Have someone a idea?

Comment: Copy the previous value into a different variable before parsing?

Comment: You need to store the previous value somewhere. You can have an object that does that so you can reuse it in all places you need as well as unit testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a copy of the previous value, and if the parse failed copy it back in:

```
var previousValue = 1;
if(!int.TryParse(input, out var number))
{
   number = previousValue;
}
```